# How can I see the post data when I call a webapi?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Is it possible to view or debug the post sent to a webapi?

`var parameters = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
     parameters.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("currency", "BTC"));
     httpContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(parameters);
     HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("/public/currency",content);`

I want to know what is sent, cannot figure how? Do I have to use fiddler?

This is what I try to view ----->

POST /path/script.cgi HTTP/1.0
From: frog@jmarshall.com
User-Agent: HTTPTool/1.0
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 32

home=Cosby&favorite+flavor=flies

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiddler is the best way to actually look at the actual HTTP Request and Responses.  I use it every day for stuff like this. You can also use the built in dev tools in which ever browser you are using.  If you are not familiar with the browser dev tools, I would suggest learning them.  They are super handy.  Check out chrome's documentation here. --https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/index

Comment: I tried with fiddler, my address is a https. Maybe this is why I didn't get a conventional http request post. I got something like tunnel established with host...maybe the post request is encrypt and cannot be read by fiddler.

Comment: Fiddler can decrypt this traffic.  Follow these instructions. http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/configure-fiddler/tasks/decrypthttps